# Dynamic Cell height sometimes not reflecting

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, uitableview

I am changing the cell height with regard to available image height of different data and updating the constraints of the cell of UITableViewCell.

I have a number of pages in my app which is same as friends in Facebook and each page includes 1 or more feeds.

Now, the problem is that when I am selecting a number of pages to send the data on UITableViewCell, it is not reflecting the updated cell height. It is taking a default value.

But, on the other hand, when I am selecting a single page to send the data, it is coming updated.

Although, the calculated cell height for both the cases is coming same. (Checked by debugging and printing the log).

I am using this code to update the Image height constraints.

```
[cell.userImage updateConstraints];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
```

Please suggest any solution

Comment: try this dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{      [cell.userImage updateConstraints];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];   
});

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
[cell.userImage updateConstraints]; 
[cell layoutIfNeeded]; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because there must be so many running on running thread, it would be better to put this on different thread.

Try using,

```
 dispatch_async
```